# How to define a ConfigurationOf with a #development version that depends on a baseline?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, metacello

In Pharo, I want to define a Metacello's `ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris` that has just one package:

```
ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>baseline01: spec
  <version: '0.1-baseline'>

  spec
    for: #common
    do: [ 
      spec
        blessing: #baseline;
        repository: 'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/DamienCassou/Nand2Tetris/main';
        package: 'Nand2Tetris' ]

ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>development: spec
  <symbolicVersion: #development>

  spec for: #common version: '0.1-baseline'.
```

When I execute `MetacelloToolBox validateConfiguration: ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris` I always get 2 warnings:

- Warning: Symbolic version #development refers to a version'0.1-baseline' whose blessing #baseline is not #development { notDevelopmentVersion } [ #validateVersionSpecForSymbolicVersion:symbolicVersion: ]
- Warning: Only baseline defined (no version defined). { onlyBaselineVersion } [ #validatePragmas ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to just depend on a baseline, the metaphor for that in Metacello is to 
use the `#bleedingEdge` blessing. Also, you can explicitly deny other symbolic versions:

```
ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>baseline01: spec
  <version: '0.1-baseline'>

  spec
    for: #common
    do: [ 
      spec
        blessing: #baseline;
        repository: 'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/DamienCassou/Nand2Tetris/main';
        package: 'Nand2Tetris' ]

ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>bleedingEdge: spec
  <symbolicVersion: #bleedingEdge>
  spec for: #common version: '0.1-baseline'.

ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>development: spec
  <symbolicVersion: #'development'>
  spec for: #'common' version: #'notDefined'.

ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>stable: spec
  <symbolicVersion: #'stable'>
  spec for: #'common' version: #'notDefined'.
```

The idea here is that `#stable` and `#development` versions link to explicitely enumbered versions, whereas `#bleedingEdge` always points to the latest versions.

This should avoid the first warning. I think, as long as you do not have released a version, you can safely ignore the second warning.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you'll define your baseline and then also a `#versionN:` method:

```
ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>version01: spec
  <version: '0.1' imports: #('0.1-baseline')>

  spec
    for: #common do: [ 
      spec
        blessing: #baseline;
        package: 'Nand2Tetris' with: 'Nand2Tetris-yourname.22'].
```

Comment: thank you. The problem is that I'm creating many mcz and I don't want to update the version number all the times.

Comment: That's fine: mark it as `#development`. Periodically update `#version01:`, or ignore the warnings until you're ready to release a new version.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to implement :

```
ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>version01: spec

<version: '0.1' imports: #('0.1-baseline' )>

spec for: #'common' do: [
    spec blessing: #'development'.
    spec description: 'some description'.
    spec author: 'yourName'.
    spec timestamp: '1/15/2013 16:13'.
    spec  
        package: 'Nand2Tetris' with: 'Nand2Tetris-yourName.versionNumber']
```

Then you should change :

```
ConfigurationOfNand2Tetris>>development: spec

  <symbolicVersion: #development>

  spec for: #'common' version: '0.1'.
```

Comment: Thank you Clement. Still I don't want to specify 'versionNumber' because it changes a lot these days :-)

Comment: @DamienCassou if it changes that much, you most definitely want a `#bleedingEdge`